# One application with two independent activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am developing simple application with only two activities.

- Activity C configures application
- Activity A for interaction with user when some event occur

It is not possible for user to navigate from the one to  the other - this is why I call them independent activities. Further more activity A is being invoked only form event, there is no way for user to do it manually.

Problem. Let's assume that application is properly configured. Some event occurs in the system, so application A is being shown to the user. The user interact with it and activity goes to background. Then the user decides to launch configuration activity C. Activity C is shown to the user. The user uses back button to "close" activity, but instead of android launcher or desktop the user is being shown activity A (taken from history).

Similar scenario might happen the other way. C is being used by user, then taken to background. Some event shows activity A and user using back button goes to C instead of closing activity A.

I have solved the problem, but the solution is pretty dirty. Is there any **clean** or **standard** way of solving such problem?

Part of my solution includes what was suggested in one answer:

snippet from AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
  android:name=".C"
  android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
  android:excludeFromRecents="false"
  android:launchMode="singleTask"
  ...
 >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
  android:exported="false"
  android:name=".A"
  android:excludeFromRecents="true"
  android:noHistory="true"
  android:launchMode="singleInstance"
  android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
  ....
>
</activity>
```

snippet from activity A:

```
public boolean onKeyUp(final int p_keyCode, final KeyEvent p_event) {
    switch(p_keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MUTE:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER:
            this.finish();
            break;
        ....
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(p_keyCode, p_event);
}
```

snipped from event handler:

```
public class H extends BroadcastReceiver {
...
  Intent intent = new Intent(p_context, A.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  p_context.startActivity(intent);
...
}
```

It works for my application. However I want application (activity C) to appear in *Recent* application. But once activity A is invoked application is removed from *Recent*.

Comment: so what you want is your previous activities to be `finish();`ed upon moving to another one?

Comment: You don't need to finish your current activity, you can only move it to background, like I suggested. And also, notice that including the power button in the switch-case list creates a new problem: The application would close when the user locks his screen. I don't know if this is proposital, but default Android behaviour dictates that this is wrong.

Comment: Activity A should be only used when some event occurs. When user decides lock the screen the reason for interaction with activity A is invalidated. Currently there is no code in C that relates to application state, therefore I am not showing it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the cleanest way to do this, but you can override the `void onBackPressed()` activity method. This way you can mannually move your activity to the background, like this, and prevent the previous activity from popping in:

```
public void onBackPressed () {
    moveTaskToBack (true);
}
```

**Edit:** Turns out there's a better way to do this:

Open your `AndroidManifest.xml`, and inside each  declaration put the following: `android:noHistory="true"``. Doing so will tell Android that your activity does not leave a history, and therefore, when the user hits back Android will quit the application, since there's no other activity for it to return to.

Comment: _noHistory_ is not an option for activity C. It invokes other activity to choose contact from address book. Therefore it must remain in history stack so the android knows where to deliver result.

Comment: Then the simplest way to achieve this is implementing my first solution. Actually both are kind the same, but the second one demands less code and is less intrusive. On the other hand, the first is far more customizable.

Comment: When I work with the code at the moment I am starting to believe that your firs solution is indeed the cleanest way to achieve what I want. I might use too unnecessary android:... properties or too many flags while invoking activity A. So any additional suggestions would be nice. Thank you for you help.